# How to return an embedded window to windows as parent

Tags: delphi, embed, delphi-xe5

I'm using ShellExecute to launch Adobe Reader. After that I'm redirecting the window to a panel with WinApi.Windows.SetParent. Now when I close my app, Adobe Reader is still active in memory and I have to end the process in the Task Manager before i can open a new session.

My questions are: How do I acces Adobe Reader in my app? How do i talk to it? (Sending messages like close and minimilize) And how do I return it to windows as parent? All of this in Delphi XE5

EDIT:

This is the code I use to set the new parent:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar('C:\Tool\Temp.pdf'), nil,  nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
Sleep(500);
wHandle := FindWindow(NIL,'Temp.pdf - Adobe Reader');
WinApi.Windows.SetParent(wHandle, Panel1.Handle);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong solution to whatever your problem is

Comment: `SetParent(Reader, Windows)`. If that fails use `0`. Or use `GetParent` to save the previous parent to be on the safe side (who knows whom else might have parented it before you do).

Comment: Setting parent assumes that you know window handle, so you can send WM_QUIT to this handle. But general approach seems wrong.

Comment: So how do I find the handle when the panel is the parent? I actually think this is the underlying question

Comment: Er, you called `SetParent` and passed the window handle. So you already have it.

Comment: I only need the reader to show documents my app generates using Debenu PDF Library. I bet im gonna walk into a few walls along the road. E.g A user that doesnt have acrobat reader as its default PDF viewer. But I'll hit that when the time comes

Comment: You'll have no end of problems trying to reparent some unsuspecting app into your process. You are not supposed to parent cross process. You only can as a sop to 16 bit compat. You should refrain from doing this.

Comment: Right. So what do you think i should use to view pdf's within my app?

Comment: Use the Adobe Reader ActiveX control...

Answer (score 2):

Here are the answers to my own questions:

- I have the handle saved to the wHandle var. Since this is global variable, I can acces it anywhere in my code. E.g. The OnClose event of my form
- To 'talk' to Abobe Reader I have to use the SendMessage method and pass the required parameters. I can use wHandle to point to Adobe Reader. The Parent of Adobe Reader is actually no issue.
- When I want to return Adobe Reader to Windows as parent, I simply change the NewParent parameter of SetParent from Panel1.Handle to 0.

I got the answer by reading the comments of my question. They all pointed my in the right direction.